# Power BI | Filter and select values higher than a reference, GIVEN ADDITIONAL conditions

Tags: excel, database, powerbi

I've been recently hired as an intern, and a challenge my area has come accross is how to highlight the closest available medical appointment.

Of course, I know that in excel such a thing would be pretty simple, with a matrixial formula like `{=MIN(IF( range > current_date_and_time ; range ))}` and as such, in PowerBi it should be just as simple.

However, the PowerBi table the area is dealing with shows the entire agenda and another column indicates if it has been reserved or not (with a 1 and 0). So, I'm wondering how to incorporate this condition toe excel formula, and in the end, how to get the **closest AVAILABLE appointment in the agenda**.

Eventually, the idea is to apply this "filter" for each doctor, and then aggregate by area.

I also know that good manners dictate I show you the data, but this is work related, so I can't do that.

Thanks beforehand, and sorry for the trouble

Comment: You don't have to show **real** data. But you should be able to create **sample** data that demonstrates the problem. (*Along with your efforts to solve the problem*).  And your sample data should be posted as text that can be easily copy/pasted into a worksheet.  Not just a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem has been solved, though by means of a different answer. THANKS