# POWER BI | Anti-Join (sorta) tables with non-equal rows and columns, but share a KEY

Tags: powerbi, dax

In relation to a previous post by me:
[Power BI | Filter and select values higher than a reference, GIVEN ADDITIONAL conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67217878/power-bi-filter-and-select-values-higher-than-a-reference-given-additional-co)

I've gotten a better understanding of the data I'm dealing with, which, by the way, it's updated constantly because it is fed by a medical agenda system.

Te databse has:

- Table A has all the medical appoitnment slots (free and Taken), each with a unique key
- Table B has the slots that have been taken. Of course, this table has some of they keys found in Table A

The tables don't have the same number of rows, nor exactly the same columns.

So, I guess I have to options:

- Compare the Keys between tables A and B, and "highlight" the rows in A that have the same keys as B
- Create Table C, a copy of A, except that the rows that have the same keys as B have been dropped., Hence, the ANTI-JOIN in the title.

Personally, I think that the anti-join is better as the other tables can be left CLEAN.

However, I believe antijoin requires both tables to have the same number of rows, so I guess I'm stuck with using queries and DAX to create the table.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The first suggestion would be to address the comment under the related post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has already been solved, though with another method. THANKS: